# Solution of nonlinear second order ODE is global

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y:[0,\infty]\to \mathbb R$ be a solution to:

$$\begin{aligned}y''(t) &= -\sin(y(t)^2)\text{   for } t>0\\y(0) &= y_0\\y'(0)&=y_1
\end{aligned}  $$

Now I'd like to show that the solution is global.

Is there a usual way how to do this? Unfortunately, I am not that familiar with ODEs.

Thanks, Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Picard's theorem on any arbitrary strip both $f(y,t)=-\sin (y^2)$ and $f_y(y,t)$ are bounded thus there exists a unique solution on the strip and this can be extented to $[0,\infty)$

Comment: But this is a second order ODE, so is Picard applicable?

Comment: @Peter Higher order ODEs can be represented as first order systems. In particular, your equation can be written as $$\begin{bmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} y \\ -\sin(x^2) \end{bmatrix}$$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $|y''(t)|\le1$, from where
$$
|y'(t)|\le|y'(0)|+|t|,\quad |y(t)|\le|y(0)|+|y'(0)|\,|t|+\frac{t^2}{2}
$$
for all $t$ for which the solution is defined. The solution is bounded on any interval it is defined. This implies that the solution is global.

Comment: How can I justify this implication?

Comment: @Peter It arises from iterated Picard iteration. One applies Picard iteration starting at zero, then starting at the endpoints of the result of that, then at the endpoints of the result of that, etc. One can check that if the solution is bounded say by $M$ then the intervals can be taken to be of size proportional to $1/M$. Consequently a solution can be defined on the whole line, because we can run Picard iteration some finite number of times to get a solution at any given point.

Comment: If the solution is not global, there is a maximal time of existence $T$ and $\lim_{t\to T^-}y(t)=\infty$.